# Does an ERC-721 contract maintain state between mintings?

Tags: solidity, evm

Does an ERC-721 contract maintain state between mintings? In other words, is the contract static in the EVM?

I want to know if this will prevent running the _mintFor more than 100 times total.

```
uint constant maxCalls = 100;

struct Object {
    uint256 property;
}

Object[] public objects;

function _mintFor(address _to, uint256 _id) internal override {
    require (
        objects.length < maxCalls,
        "Max calls reached. Can't make any more objects."
    );
    
    objects.push (
        Object(0123456789)
    );
    
    _safeMint(_to, _id);
}        

function getObjectCount() public view returns (uint256) {
    return objects.length;
}
```

If I call getObjectCount after each minting, will the object count be incremented by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if `objects` is a variable at contract level then changes will be persisted between transactions.